# Auto resizing multiple textareas on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

These are snippets that auto re-size a single textarea:

http://jsfiddle.net/ImpressiveWebs/fGNNT/1333/

http://jsfiddle.net/CbqFv/

For example in the first link above, this is the textarea:

```
<textarea id="comments" placeholder="Type many lines of texts in here and you will see magic stuff" class="common"></textarea>
```

and it resizes when text is entered.

However, with

```
<textarea id="comments" placeholder="Type many lines of texts in here and you will see magic stuff" class="common"></textarea>

<textarea id="comments" placeholder="Type many lines of texts in here and you will see magic stuff" class="common"></textarea>
```

only the first one is resizing. How do I make the second one also to resize?

Comment: resize in context of `width/heigth?`.make sure you have unique `ID's` to each elements.o/w use common `class`

Comment: you are only allowed to have one element with the same ID, you seem to use comments as ID for both

Comment: GetElementById returns just one element.  You have to get the two textareas for example by tag name getElementsByTagName and iterate over the returned array and attach event handlers to each of them. And be aware that the same id may onlybe used once in a html document.

Comment: Oh ok I understood now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine http://jsfiddle.net/fGNNT/2219/. Use the class for identification instead of the ID

```
// Bad
var txt = $('#comments'),
    hiddenDiv = $(document.createElement('div')),
    content = null;

// Good and working
var txt = $('.common'),
    hiddenDiv = $(document.createElement('div')),
    content = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

`id` must be unique, here you declared two divs with same id `comments` ; as you have attached your event to an id, it can't work because the function `getElementById` returns only one element (the first found in the dom, that's why your second textarea doesn't resize.

Either you can use `class` instead of div, or attach your event to the `textarea` element, not to a specific div